# Nginx Docker haven't access to server through server_name

Tags: ssl, docker, nginx

I have the issue with my `Nginx` configuration, I can't set my server_name.
I tried to build my docker container with `Nginx` configuration inside.

Body of my `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
RUN chown -R root:root /etc/nginx/ssl
RUN chmod -R 600 /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY etc/ssl/certs/qwobbleprod.crt /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY etc/ssl/certs/app.qwobble.com.key /etc/nginx/ssl

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 443
```

and my `Nginx` configuration file ->

```
server {
  listen      443 ssl default_server;
  root        /usr/share/nginx/html;

  server_name blabla.com www.blabla.com;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/blabla.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/blabla.com.key;

  sendfile on;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }

}
```

I tried to build and run my docker container

```
docker build -t <name> .
docker run -it -p 443:443 <name>
```

As the result, I have my app on https://localhost:443
but I haven't access to my app through https://blabla.com:443 or https://www.blabla.com:443

I'm a newbie in working with `Docker` and `Nginx`, and I have no idea what is wrong.
I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: As you are only hosting one site the server name isn't important. You already have `listen` saying this is the default since 443 is the port any requests to that port would go to docker and the nginx inside. nginx would see this is to the default site.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would expect that you actually need the blabla.com domain and that the dns (Domain Name Service) should point to your external IP address.

You must then configure the router to accept connections on port 443 (what you desire) and point (port forwarding) it to the computer running your docker image on the port that it is actually running on.

It might also be necessary to open firewall settings on the computer docker is running on.

I see you also want to listen to https so you might need some certificates for that.

or if you want to fake it you can edit your `hosts` file (on mac or linux `/etc/hosts`) and add an entry like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 blabla.com
```

but now blabla.com will only work on your machine...

Hope it helps